# Best way to stop specific JavaScript function on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my current project, I am using parallax scrolling on the website, and am currently developing the mobile/tablet versions of the site.

At current, parallax scrolling doesn't work well on tablets and mobiles due to the difference in the scroll event, so I am wanting to disable the javascript calls in my scripts file when a mobile device is detected. At the moment I am doing this using

`if ( $(window).width() > 960) {`

and then firing my parallax code. I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this that will target devices rather than resolution, as I am aware that a lot of the screens on the market will exceed 960px in width.

The current version of the site is available at http://beta.residencyradio.com if you want to see how it works, but any help at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution to Detect Mobile Devices**

Check out the [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) website. There are a series of scripts for different languages, including JavaScript, that can be used to include different behavior when a mobile browser is detected.

The scripts, by default, will simply load another URL if a mobile browser is detected. It is designed to load the mobile version of your website if a mobile device is detected.

However, with a slight modification, you can use the script to set a "flag" that you can use when determining whether to perform a different behavior, yet still load the same website for all devices. I modified the code below with an `alert("mobile detected")` placeholder entry below:

```
isMobile=false;(function(a,b){if(/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))alert("mobile detected")})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
```

Near the end of this script, where it says `alert("mobile detected")` just replace that with `isMobile=true`. If the script detects a mobile browser, that flag will be set to true.

I left the alert in there so you can run the script with different devices to see the alert.

**Form Factors and Design Tips**

Now, I do want to point out that the form factors for mobile, tablet, and desktop are vastly different. Additionally, the way users interact with these 3 form factors is also drastically different. This may mean that building one website for all 3 platforms may either harm usability and prevent you from creating the best user experience for all 3 platforms.

In my experience, the mobile and tablet websites that I've enjoyed using the most were designed specifically for those devices. In other words, they weren't just existing websites or Web applications that someone modified in an attempt to make things "fit" the mobile and tablet platforms.

Instead, the mobile and tablet versions of those websites with a high degree of usability were designed, from the ground up, independent of the desktop version, so that updates, bugfixes, design changes, etc, could all be made just to one platform so the two could diverge independently to fit the use cases for users on each platform.

For example, I recently built two Web forms, one is designed for desktop browsers and the other is designed for mobile browsers. The desktop version is in one HTML file and the mobile version is in another HTML file. The mobile version uses jQuery Mobile, so it has touch, slide, and other capabilities that make interacting with the site a pleasure on mobile devices. It also feels more like a mobile app and feels more "native". The desktop version has more UI elements that involve mouse-clicks or keyboard shortcuts, and looks more like a website than a mobile app.

Since I don't know the exact details of your application, you'll of course want to take a look at what you're doing and ask yourself if it would be easier and more user friendly if you created mobile/tablet versions independent of the desktop version.

Comment: Ah this is very useful, I seen this before but couldn't get it working. So with what you said, I have changed the relevant bits, but can seem to get the code to fire, here's a small example of what I have : http://pastie.org/3795765

So therefore I am wanting to fire the code if the browser detected isn't mobile, however this doesn't seem to work, but I can't figure out why?

Comment: In your pastebin, you have `if (isMobile=false) {` when what you really want is `if (isMobile == false) {`. Try fixing that, and you should, in theory, be fine.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick, don't know how I didn't spot that, thanks dude. As for what you are saying about building the different sites, its something that I have considered and to be honest ill probably end up doing in a few weeks time, depending on how my testing goes on tablets. For the moment this is more of a quick fix to get the site working on all devices initially. Thanks for the help dude!

Comment: by the way, for anyone like me, who wanted the ipad treated like a mobile device, where it says `ip(hone|od)` change it to `ip(hone|od|ad)`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the Modernizr.touch test in this case. Like you say, it's common that touch events are only fired on the completion of a 'scroll' on a touch device.

Comment: You should consider including a link and also an example in your answer. It will help others who have this same problem, and will make it easier for them to decide which route to go. :)

Comment: Using touch support is a bad idea IMHO : lots of false positive (computers with touchscreen) and not future-friendly (what if touch Macbooks appears in six months ?)

Comment: I didn't actually know that modernizer was capable of this, even though I use it in all my sites! @jmort253 's solution works best for what I want at the moment, from testing pretty much all parallax plugins, mobile browsers don't tend to handle them well at the moment, quite jittery and then the touch event issue. In an ideal world it would react just how it does on the desktop browser but at the moment they just don't. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @mddw makes a good point. I still think `Modernizr.touch` is a great test to use in conjunction with the OP's existing test. If you're designing/coding for mobile then chances are you're already using Modernizr; why add another script?