# Javascript not recognizing a mobile operating system when Firefox mobile is used

Tags: firefox, mobile, detection

I am using the following javascript to detect a browser running on a mobile operating system.

```
 function isMobile() {

var index = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mobile");
return (index > -1);
```

}

I am testing the javascript from my Android based smartphone (HTC EVO LTE)

The script identifies a mobile operating system when I use Chrome or when I use Android's default "internet browser."  It does not identify a mobile operating system when I use Firefox.  Why is this happening?  Is there a simple fix?

Comment: What is the value of `navigator.appVersion` ?

Comment: This looks like a pretty bad way to detect mobile browsers. There are better solutions around, hold on, I'll look one up....

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript. Solution to detect mobile browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser)

Comment: Please show us the entire contents of the navigator object in Firefox OS. I don't have Firefox OS, so I can't as easily look it up as you could easily add it to the question as an [edit].

Comment: When you visit this from Firefox OS, does it know it's mobile:  http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/. If so, [this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10165289/552792) explains how you might use the script to perform different behavior on your site.

Comment: not sure what you mean @rene.  The firefox app version is Firefox 22.

Comment: Thanks, @Pekka, for the reference to the possible duplicate.  That solution works fine!